# Can an image be made resizing itself using HTML?

Tags: html

Using HTML, can an image be made resizing itself according to screen resolution? Like if scrolling is not needed to view a complete image on a large screen but it's needed on a small screen, can it resize itself so that scrolling is not needed even on a small screen with a particular aspect ratio using HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting  max size in %, like that:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}    ​
```

Comment: Can give an example code for an image named abc.jpg which can resize itself according to the size of display area of any browser?

Comment: and yes, minimum width was excessive

Answer (score 0):

Akhtar,

To some degree you may not want to disable scrolling.  If a user has a high zoom setting they should be able to scroll left and right to view your page or else some of the page will not be available.  e.g.  http://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/

If I zoom on this page there is no left right scroll available to me in Chrome.

Aside from that, using % is a good way to get your content looking good for most browsers and settings.  You can set your images, containers, body, etc. with % height or width.  Keep in mind that in order to maintain your aspect ratio of pics, you will need to set the width and then auto set the height.

```
<style>
.leftColumn{width:20%;}
.leftColumn{width:80%;}
.somePic{width:20%;height:auto;}
.somePic2{width:80%;height:auto;}
</style>

<body>

<div class="leftColumn">
<img class="somePic" src="somePic.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="rightColumn">
<img class="somePic2" src="somePic2.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
```

If this is not acceptable for you then as far as I know you would need to use a scripting language in order to get each user's screen size.  You could then code much more detailed settings depending on the reported screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, (I hope I understand your question clearly)

**Css**

```
  #myimage{
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

**Markup**

```
<img src='xyz.jpg' id='myimage' />
```

or use you can use inline style if this seems difficult, just place this code inside `body` tag.

```
<img src='xyz.jpg' style='bottom:0;left:0;position:fixed;right:0;top: 0;width: 100%; />
```

Comment: If you dont know how to place css , you can use inline style. I've updated the answer. See now.

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of Percentage metric in styling is based upon viewport which is basically based upon screen resolution. i.e 100% width div is 800 px wide in 800x600 and 1024px in 1024*768. Why do you care for resolution? Style your image in % if you want flexibility.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/upavn/

Comment: Browsers accept it as pictures's 100% size. My question actually is that if a picture of size 200x900 is there, on a screen of resolution 1600x900 it won't need scrolling but on a screen of 800x600, scrolling would be needed. I want the picture resizing itself to 800x600 automatically with maintenance of it's(picture's) aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can have either `width` or `height` set at `100%`, but not both, unless you use javascript.

CSS3 has nice property for that called [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size):

```
background:url(../images/myimage.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size:cover;
```

[background-size example](http://jsbin.com/aqocaf)

It's supported in most browsers, except, you know, IE < 9. Support table: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

If you go the javascript route there are many plugins like [supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) or [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/).